# this is missing, in react input onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the onChange function I have no this, so no props and no state what am i doing wrong ? thanks

Edit: added class and constructor!

```
export default class Editor extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sortDirection: true,
      json: props.json, // using a prop called json. were setting state.data to json
      options: props.options || {}, //optional object options
      id:props.id,
    }
  }
 onChange = (e) => {
    let xyz=this
    /// this is undefined. needed to set state on controlled input
   }


buildKeys = () => {
    let keys = Object.keys(this.state.json[0]);
    let self = this
    return keys.map((key, index) => {
      // hide column if columname in hidden columns array
      /// if no hidecol option we set it an empty array
      let hiddenColArr = self.state.options.hideCol || []
      // loops throgh hiddenCol array and returns a bool
      let isHidden =  _.includes(hiddenColArr, key) 

     // build values
     let arrIndex=this.props.id -1
     let row = this.state.json[arrIndex];

     return Object.keys(row).map((key2)  =>

     <div key={shortid.generate()} className='row'   >{key}
    ////////////////*Input added here/
        <input  onChange={this.onChange} key={shortid.generate()} type="text" value={row[key2]} />
    /////////////////Input end here/

     </div>

     )

}
```

Comment: ["this" in arrow functions](https://www.codementor.io/dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc)

Comment: @Olian04 thanks for the link interesting link

Comment: Are you sure it's undefined in onChange? I don't see how.

Comment: @DaveNewton i know, i asked myself the same thing, but it's deffo not there

Comment: Can you post a codesandbox replicating your issue? I can't replicate your bug myself

Comment: `<input onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}` or `<input onChange={this.onChange.bind(this}` - although `onChange = (e) => {` should work fine without that.

Comment: @ChrisG an inline lambda on the handler does the binding for you.. aka `onChange = (e) => {`

Comment: @ChrisG no need if using arrows

Comment: Unable to repo. Is this a function or class component?

Comment: its a class  comp with a function @JohnRuddell i shall try it's a big proj , so will take me 30-40 mins, will ping here when done. thx all

Comment: Why that long? Just create a [mre].

Comment: @say, just making a [mcve] should do it, no need to expose your full project

Comment: How do you transpile your code, btw? And do you have class properties enabled with the babel plugin? (in case you use babel)

Comment: @Icepickle i'm using create react app which is using Babel/WebPack if i'm not mistaken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using class notation (your only choice as of React 16), you need to use arrow functions, i.e. `<Thing onChange={() => this.onChange()} .../>`. in order to preserve `this`.

If you don't, by the time `onChange` fires, the execution context for that call is guaranteed to not be your component, and is most likely just `window`.

You'll also want to change those instance properties to normal class functions:

```
class Thing extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ...
  }

  onChange(evt) {
    // do what needs to be done
  }

  render() {
    return <div ... >
      <input onChange={evt => this.onChange(evt)} ... />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

In fact, if you're using Babel + Webpack, I can almost guarantee you that's already what Babel will do to your code, so the code that *runs* will have normal class functions, and so you really need that arrow function as onChange handler.

(some tutorials advocate putting `this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)` in your constructor, which I would not recommend you do. It's not your constructor's job to known what the rest of the class looks like)

Comment: but, he is using class properties (well, I assume the arrow functions are part of the a class component)

Comment: I didn't think so, but then i tried it and now have access to this. nice explanation, ping me an article if u have 1 handly.. cheers Mike

Comment: @saj you can totally access state / props in an arrow function. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-786rm. You must've been doing something incorrectly.

Comment: @JohnRuddell thanks for the exampl I agree, i'm doing that my self back in mo

Comment: Using instance properties instead of functions makes very little sense, though. If you run it through Babel, for instance, it will (_rightly so_) convert your instance properties back to real class functions.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I wish i understood enough to have a discussion with you :(

Comment: the methods defined as a lambda are translated to a definition in the constructor. However babel and pretty much every compiler out there accept this syntax. I'd say it makes sense because they aren't properties but rather methods.

Comment: You are right Mike that it depends on the transpiler behind the scenes to convert them into functions, I assumed from the code shared in the OP that they were class properties or whatever they call them now :)  A bit more info on why constructor binding wouldn't be appropriate anymore would be interesting though (seen it has been advocated for quite a while)

Comment: yup im using Babel

Comment: Mike, looking at what [react suggests](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) they are pretty open to any approach, so is it your personal preference?

Comment: It is, based on a career that predates React's invention (and I absolute love React. Just this part of it is idiotic). Your constructor should not be responsible for creating derivative functions from its prototype to bind them to itself, that's just needless shadowing, and increases both your maintenance and bug surface.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `this` to your functions by binding it in your constructor:

```
...
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onChange = this.onchange.bind(this);
}
...
```

Comment: thanks but I don't want to and should not have to see Mike's answer below 'It's not your constructor's job to known what the rest of the class looks like'

Comment: I didn't think about it that way. Thanks!

Comment: @saj This is a pretty common approach. The constructor already "knows" about class details anyway--it's the ctor of the class.